# Why did Daleks invade Earth after stealing it?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Season 4 finale, Davros and Daleks teleported Earth into *Medusa Cascade*. They were going to use Earth as a part of transmitter to demolish the reality itself.

What was the point of invading the Earth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Earth is a well known hub of anti-Dalek activity. Note that their [primary targets](http://web.archive.org/web/20120330161328/http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Doctor_Who/Doctor_Who_4x12_-_The_Stolen_Earth.pdf) seem to be facilities and locations that have shown an ability to defend the Earth against alien assaults in previous serials:

- **Unit HQ**
- **The Valiant**
- **Torchwood**
- **New York** (HQ of the United Nations)
- **London** (the site of the Torchwood anti-Sycorax weapon seen in "[The Christmas Invasion](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Christmas_Invasion)")

---

They expend a considerable amount of time looking for the Doctor

> **DAVROS :** *I mean, is there news of him?*
>
> **SUPREME DALEK :** *Negative! No reports of Time Lord. We are beyond the Doctor's reach!*

---

They also need to "harvest" a considerable number of humans (including Jackie, Mickey and Rose) to test their destructo-ray on.